# How to get the intersection between two bi-dimensional Arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, intersection

I want to get the intersection between two bi-dimensional arrays and return it as a bi-dimensional array as the Function declared here:

```
Private Function GetIntersection(ByVal Array2D1 As String(,), ByVal Array2D2 As String(,)) As String(,)
```

Comment: How do you want the comparing to be done? a1(x, ?) with all of a2(?, ?) or a1(x, ?) with a2(x, ?).

Comment: For Example: a1(0, 0) = {{"2" , "Name"}} a1(0, 1) = {{"3", "Name"}} a2(0, 0) = {{"3", "Name"}} a2(0,1) = {{"3", "Keyword"}}. All elements of a1 that also belong to a2 (or equivalently, all elements of a2 that also belong to a1) Then, a3(0, 0) = {{"3", "Name"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Pair : Implements IEquatable(Of Pair) 'Defines a generalized method that a value type or class implements to create a type-specific method for determining equality of instances.
'the Pair values to compare
Public Report As String
Public Match As String

'Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
Public Function Equals1(p As Pair) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Pair).Equals
    Return Report = p.Report And Match = p.Match
End Function

'A hash code intended for efficient lookup in collections that are based on a hash table.
Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Dim hashReport = Report.GetHashCode()
    Dim hashMatch = Match.GetHashCode()
    Return hashReport Xor hashMatch
End Function
```

End Class

```
 Private Function GetIntersection(ByVal one As List(Of Pair), ByVal second As List(Of Pair)) As List(Of Pair)
    Dim intersection As New List(Of Pair)

    If second.Count = 0 Then
        second = one
    End If
    intersection = one.Intersect(second).ToList
    Return intersection
End Function
```